# How to add comments to networkx edgelist?

Tags: python, file-io, networkx

Network has a function `nx.write_edgelist(G, path, comments='#', delimiter=' ', data=True, encoding='utf-8')`.

I'd like to add some comments to the graph I created. However, it turns out that the argument `comments` is of no use in this case. When the following command is executed:

```
nx.write_edgelist(my_graph,my_path,comments="#some comments",data=False);
```

Nothing related to the comments is written to the output file.
Is there any way that I can add comments to an edgelist other than create an edgelist and add the comments mannually (or writing a program to add the comments after the edgelist file is created).

Comment: The `comments` argument is intended to be a string that denotes the start of a comment in the file.  This is used by `read_edgelist` to ignore a line, but it looks to me that `write_edgelist` and `write_weighted_edgelist` don't actually make use of `comments` at all.  I don't see a way to do it other than after the fact editing (which you could do by opening the file in python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Networkx 2.0, the argument `comments` in the `nx.write_edgelist` function is of no use.